# block cipher in CTR mode manipulation

Tags: security, encryption

I have a question about block cipher using CTR mode. I think i need to find something (value) that when I do `46 XOR value = 43,` I get value to be `(1011 1101)`, then i use `0x64(0110 0100) XOR value(1011 1101)` but it does not give me `0x72(0111 0010)`. Did I miss something here? My upstanding is that in order to do this, all i need to do is to find a value that adds counter (in this case is zero) and xor the plain text to get cipher text.  Did I miss something here? Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that the 2nd and 3rd block were created by the same key stream (created by concatenating the counter values encrypted by the block cipher).

So for the first byte of the second block you'd have 46 = 43 ^ KK and 51 = P2 ^ KK where KK is the first byte of the key stream. Now KK can be easily calculated, as KK = 46 ^ 43 (KK = 05 if I'm not mistaken). Now P2 = KK ^ 51 or P2 = 05 ^ 51 = 54.

You can simply repeat that for each index into the streams and presto. You don't have to do anything with the counter itself; knowing that the same key and counter were used is enough to generate the same key stream.